# How to get reference to the cell from user function

Tags: ios, swift3, uitableview

I create my custom cell with UILabel and Button inside. After I connect the UIButton as action in my Controller. If touch up the Button it changes the image how intended, but what I want is, that after the touch to change the backgoundcolor of the UILabel too. How to get reference to my custom cell.

```
@IBAction func selectCell(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if sender.imageView?.image == UIImage(named: "do") {
        sender.setImage(UIImage(named: "done"), for: .normal)
    } else {
        sender.setImage(UIImage(named: "do"), for: .normal)
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show your `cellForRowAt indexPath`

Comment: `UIImage(named: "do")` produces another new instance of `UIImage` every time, which will always be different from your already set image. Hence your condition will always fall in `else` case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why not use a delegate system ? This would allow you to get a reference to your cell easily.

In you cell.swift

```
@objc protocol CellDelegate: class {
    func buttonPressed(forCell cell: Cell)
}
```

Then in your cell class : you need to have a delegate property, your IBAction method, and a way to set your delegate:

```
class Cell {

    fileprivate weak var delegate: CellDelegate? = nil


    func setup(withDelegate delegate: CellDelegate) {
        self.delegate = delegate
    }


    @IBAction func deleteButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        if sender.imageView?.image == UIImage(named: "do") {
            sender.setImage(UIImage(named: "done"), for: .normal)
        } else {
            sender.setImage(UIImage(named: "do"), for: .normal)
        }

        delegate?.buttonPressed(forCell: self)
    }

}
```

Finally in your TableViewController : You need to setup the delegate as self during the configuration of the cell, and implement the delegate method:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cellIdentifier = viewModel.cellIdentifier(for: indexPath)

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! Cell

            cell.setup(withDelegate: self)

        return cell
    }


extension: TableViewController: CellDelegate {

    func buttonPressed(forCell cell: Cell) {
        //Do what you want
    }

}
```

That's how I tipically set actions for cells

Comment: Thank you, I totally forgot the power of delegates :))